# How do I convert this bit of C++ code to C#?

Tags: c#, c++

Trying to convert some code, but for all my googling I can't figure out how to convert this bit.

```
    float fR = fHatRandom(fRadius);
    float fQ = fLineRandom(fAngularSpread ) * (rand()&1 ? 1.0 : -1.0);
    float fK = 1;
```

This bit

```
(rand()&1 ? 1.0 : -1.0);
```

I can't figure out.

Comment: Thanks for editing that Michael I couldnt figure out how to get the second bit to show as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ sample generates a random number, uses its lowest bit and throws away the rest.  The lowest bit is then used to pick either -1 or 1.

In C#, the equivalent is as follows.

```
new Random().Next(0, 2) * 2 - 1
```

**Important**: If you do this in a loop, store the instance of `Random` somewhere and only call `Next` in the loop, not the constructor again.  This is not only a performance optimization.  You would otherwise see sequences of identical bits of duration of approximately 100 ms, so calls to the parameterless constructor of Random should be few and far between, ideally one per your app's startup.

Comment: Wouldn't a more appropriate equivalent be to use the Random.NextByteByffer method and actually do a bitwise **&** operation, like in the C++ sample?  I have no idea about performance in such examples but to me this would be closer to the original code.

Comment: @JonTaylor - Do you mean `NextBytes`?  I think that apart from getting randomness, performance and range right (same as in the C++ sample), I do not see why and how one could or should get even "closer".  However, in some contexts, `NextBytes` can produce excellent performance because you do not need to throw away any pseudo random bits.  Especially in close loops where the number of iterations is large and ideally known beforehand.

Comment: I am not a C++ or C# programmer so I may have been completely wrong :).  I only meant in terms of using a bitmask and ternary operator rather than a multiplication and subtraction to bring the random number into range.  I certainly am not saying one is better than the other because I don't have any idea which is better, however, implementation wise, the bitwise operator version seems closer.

Answer (score 7):

It's 1 or -1 with 50/50 chance.

An equivalent C# code would be:

```
((new Random().Next(0, 2)) == 0) ? 1.0 : -1.0;
```

`Next(0,2)` will return either 0 or 1.

If the code gets called a lot you should store the instance of `Random` and re-use it. When you create a new instance of `Random` it gets initialized with a seed that determines the sequence of pseudo-random numbers. In order to have better "randomness" you shouldn't re-initialize the random sequence often.

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong - it would be an exact contradiction ;-) You have to change the condition to != 0 :) Of course semantically it's identical.

Comment: Of course, I meant it's going to have the same outcome as a complete expression :)

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
Random rnd = new Random();
(rnd.NextInt(2) * 2 -1); // 1 or -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Either 1.0 or -1.0 with equal chance of either one

rand() generates a number witch is anded with 0x01 i.e. the first bit and depending on if you get a bit or not you get 1.0 or -1.0

Comment: how would I do the same thing in c#?

Answer (score 0):

You can just randomize with 50% chance, as others said.

If you want an exact translation, it would be:

```
((new Random().Next() & 1 > 0) ? 1.0 : -1.0)
```

You have to make a boolean out of the first part of conditional expression.